# Get last modified file date in a folder structure

Tags: linux

I'm trying to get the most recently modified file's (datetime - as a unixtimestamp) from a folder structure. There are many files but I only need the datetime of the most recently updated.

I'ved tried the following but I think I'm way of the mark:

```
stat --printf="%y %n\n" $(ls -tr $(find * -type f))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ls -trF | grep -v '\/\|@' | tail -1 | xargs -i date +%s -r {}
```

`ls -trF` gives you symbols to filter out, '/' for directories and '@' for links. After that, grep out those files, pick the last one, and pass it to date command.

**EDIT**: Of note as well is the `date -r` option, which will display the last modified date of file given as argument.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

`ls -ltr | tail -n1 | awk '{print "date -d\"" $6FS$7FS$8 "\" +%s"}' | sh`

EDIT:

actually better yet,try the following

`find -type f -exec ls -l --time-style +%s {} \+ | sort -n -k6 | tail -n1`

this will iterate over the folder structure you desired, print the time as a unix timestamp and sort it so the newest is at the end. (hence `tail -n1`)